# Print statement within a larger main function is not being called properly and expected output is not showing up

Tags: python, function, printing

I have a rock, paper, scissors program that works the way it needs to with one minor error. The output is supposed to state what the player chooses, what the computer chooses and then who wins for example. If player chooses rock and the computer chooses paper, the output should read:

> You chose rock. The computer chose scissors. Rock smashes scissors. Player wins!

I thought I added the last sentence to the right function, but when I run the program it does not print out as expected.

```
import random

# Function: Display Menu
# Input: none
# Output: none
# displays the game rules to the user
def displayMenu():
    print("Welcome! Let's play rock, paper, scissors.")
    print("The rules of the game are:")
    print("\tRock smashes scissors")
    print("\tScissors cut paper")
    print("\tPaper covers rock")
    print("\tIf both the choices are the same, it's a tie")

# Function: Get Computer Choice
# Input: none
# Output: integer that is randomly chosen, a number between 0 to 2
def getComputerChoice():
    computerChoice = random.randrange(0,3)
    return computerChoice

# Function: Get Player Choice
# Input: none
# Output: integer that represents the choice
# Asks the user for their choice: 0 for rock, 1 for paper, or 2 for scissors
def getPlayerChoice():
    playerChoice = int(input("Please choose (0) for rock, (1) for paper or (2) for scissors"))
    return playerChoice

# Function: Play Round
# Input: two integers--one representing the computer's choice and the other representing the player's choice
# Output: integer (-1 if computer wins, 1 if player wins, 0 if there is a tie)
# This method contains the game logic so it stimulates the game and determines a winner
def playRound(computerChoice, playerChoice):
    if playerChoice == 0 and computerChoice == 2:
        print("Rock smashes scissors. Player wins!")
        return 1
    elif computerChoice == 0 and playerChoice == 2:
        print("Rock smashes scissors. Computer wins!")
        return -1
    elif playerChoice == 2 and computerChoice == 1:
        print("Scissors cut paper. Player wins!")
        return 1
    elif computerChoice == 2 and playerChoice == 1:
        print("Scissors cut paper. Computer wins!")
        return -1
    elif playerChoice == 1 and computerChoice == 0:
        print("Paper covers rock. Player wins!")
        return 1
    elif computerChoice == 1 and playerChoice == 0:
        print("Paper covers rock. Computer wins!")
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

# Function: Continue Game
# Input: none
# Output: boolean
# Ask the user is they want to continue (Y/N), and then return True or False accordingly
def continueGame():
    playAgain = input("Do you want to continue playing? Enter (y) for yes or (n) for no.")
    if playAgain.lower() == "y":
        return True
    elif playAgain.lower() == "n":
        return False

# Function: main
# Input: none
# Output: none
def main():
    playerCounter = 0
    computerCounter = 0
    tieCounter = 0

    displayMenu()
    next_game = True

    while next_game:
        p_choice = getPlayerChoice()
        if p_choice == 0:
            choicePlayer = "rock"
        elif p_choice == 1:
            choicePlayer = "paper"
        elif p_choice == 2:
            choicePlayer = "scissors"
        c_choice = getComputerChoice()
        if c_choice == 0:
            choiceComputer = "rock"
        elif c_choice == 1:
            choiceComputer = "paper"
        elif c_choice == 2:
            choiceComputer = "scissors"
        print("You chose", choicePlayer + ".")
        print("The computer chose", choiceComputer + ".")


        result = playRound(p_choice, c_choice)
        if result == -1:
            computerCounter += 1
        elif result == 0:
            tieCounter += 1
        else:
            playerCounter += 1

        next_game = continueGame()

    print("You won", playerCounter, "game(s).")
    print("The computer won", computerCounter, "game(s).")
    print("You tied with the computer", tieCounter, "time(s).")
    print()
    print("Thanks for playing!")

# Call Main
main()
```

Comment: Show us the observed and the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the arguments in the wrong order. Your function signature expects the `computerChoice` as its first argument:

```
def playRound(computerChoice, playerChoice):
```

Therefore change the following line:

```
result =  playRound(p_choice, c_choice)
```

to

```
result =  playRound(c_choice, p_choice)
```